# Searching for an Android flashcard application which is integrated with some good dictionary

Tags: translation, german-to-english, vocabulary, software

I'm looking for application in which I could look up a meaning of the word, save it automatically as a flashcard and later practice it. Great example of this is vocabulary trainer on dict.cc, but this is only available on their website, and dict.cc android apps do not have this option.

Also, best would be if that application was using dict.cc for translations.

Answer (score 2):

For learning, try the [anki](http://ankisrs.net/) / [ankidroid](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/) combination.  In my opinion nothing can beat this system.  There are many different readymade decks for various languages, but even better than using a pre-made deck is to create your own deck while learning the language.  Therefore I would split up the task.  Look up words using google translate or some other translator, then add them to your anki deck.